# How to deal with environment variables in Python?

Tags: python, api, dictionary, environment-variables, dotenv

I am trying to access an API with Python but I don't want my keys in the main code.
Hence, I am trying to use environment variables (dotenv).

I have an ".env" file with my keys:

```
API_KEY="123"
API_PASS="ABC"
```

In my main code, there is the following code:

```
load_dotenv(".env"))
API_KEY=os.getenv("API_KEY")
API_PKEY=os.getenv("API_PKEY")
pass=bytes(API_PASS, encoding='utf8')
headers = {'Content-Type': 'xxx',
           'TAPI-ID': API_KEY}
```

But this is not working when I tried to make a request. If I put manually my keys in the main
code as:

```
pass=bytes("ABC", encoding='utf8')
headers = {'Content-Type': 'xxx',
           'TAPI-ID': "123"}
```

Then everything's fine, but I don't want to have my keys in the main code.
Also, I would like not to see the keys even if I print related variables in the main code, for example, if the code

```
pass=bytes(API_PASS, encoding='utf8')
```

works, I would like not to see "ABC" when I print(pass).

Just to be clear: I have already used dotenv in another API with success. The problem here is that I have to deal with headers and encoding and Python is not understanding my commands.

Thank you.

Comment: `.env` file is just a convention, there is no built-in support for them in Python. Your environment variables won't be magically converted to Python variables. Are you using a third party helper such as python-dotenv?

Comment: use the dotenv package is also my suggestion

Comment: I am using dotenv already (it is not clear in the question, so I edited it). I have already used dotenv in another API with success. This is not exactly the problem. The problem is that in this API, I have to deal with headers and encoding and Python is not understanding my commands.